# Solve the following trigonometric inequalities

Tags: trigonometry

I'm solving the following inequality:

$$\cos(2x+\frac \pi 3) \ge - \frac 1 2 \text{ with } -\frac \pi 2<x<\frac \pi 2$$

I found the following range of solutions:

$$\frac 4 3 \pi \leq2x+\frac \pi 3 \leq \frac 2 3 \pi$$

That I simplified with

$$\frac \pi 3 \leq 2x\leq\pi \rightarrow \frac \pi 6 \leq 2x<\frac \pi 2$$

Though, my book suggests the following solutions:

$$-\frac \pi 2< x \leq \frac \pi 6$$

Any hints on why my solution is wrong?

Comment: Well $\pi \le 2x \le \frac{\pi}{3}$ is incorrect. $\pi$ is greater than $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Set $\theta=2x+(\pi/3)$ and solve $\cos\theta\ge -1/2$ with $-2\pi/3\lt\theta\lt 4\pi/3$.

Comment: Thanks. @mathlove are you suggesting that my way of solving it is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step is to solve the inequality
$$
\cos(2x + \frac\pi3) \geq -\frac12
$$
without the additional restriction $-\frac\pi2 < x < \frac\pi2$.
It seems you attempted to do this, so that was good.

Let's write $u = 2x + \frac\pi3$ for a moment, because I think having
too many symbols in an inequality sometimes gets in the way of understanding.

We have to solve $\cos u \geq -\frac12$.
As you deduced, there are two points on the unit circle that have
$x$-coordinate $-\frac12$, and they occur at angles
$u = \frac23 \pi$ and $u = \frac 43 \pi$.
You also seem to have deduced that you want angles that are swept
out in the counterclockwise direction from the point
at $u = \frac 43 \pi$ to the point at $u = \frac23 \pi$.

Where you first went wrong was to use that conclusion to
construct the inequality
$$ \frac 43 \pi \leq u \leq \frac23 \pi.$$
Now that we have replaced the clutter of $2x + \frac\pi3$
with the single symbol $u$ in the middle of this chain of
inequalities, it may be more obvious that there is *no* value of $u$
that can possibly satisfy these inequalities;
if you could find one, you would have proved that
$\frac 43 \pi \leq \frac23 \pi$, which is not true.

In order to express a range of angles, you need the upper bound
of the range to be *greater* than the lower bound.
The way to accomplish this is to remember that each point on the
unit circle is identified by an infinite number of angle values;
for example, the point at angle $\frac43 \pi$ is also at angle
$2\pi + \frac43 \pi$, at angle $4\pi + \frac43 \pi$,
and at angle $-2\pi + \frac43 \pi$, among others.

Now, we could set the upper bound of the range to an angle equivalent to $\frac23 \pi$ and greater than $\frac43 \pi$;
or we could set the lower bound to an angle equivalent to $\frac43 \pi$ and less than $\frac23 \pi$.
I would choose the second option because I prefer angles closer to zero.
So we can try $-2\pi + \frac43 \pi = -\frac23 \pi$ as a lower bound,
that is, let the angle $u$ satisfy
$$ -\frac 23 \pi \leq u \leq \frac23 \pi.$$
Check this on a unit circle; it works.
The angle $-4\pi + \frac43 \pi = -\frac83 \pi$, although it is
equivalent to $\frac43 \pi$, would *not* be an acceptable choice, because from $-\frac83 \pi$ to $\frac23 \pi$ you travel all the way around the circle
and then some more, including angles $u$ that do not satisfy 
$\cos u \geq -\frac12$.

Now you can rewrite $-\frac 23 \pi \leq u \leq \frac23 \pi$
by replacing $u$ with its definition in terms of $x$:
$$ -\frac 23 \pi \leq 2x + \frac\pi3 \leq \frac23 \pi.$$
This is a correct version of your second displayed formula;
you should be able to get a correct solution from that.

Comment: Thanks so much David for the _excellent_ explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta = 2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}$.

Observe that the requirement that $x$ satisfies the inequalities 
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$$
implies that 
$$\theta = 2x + \frac{\pi}{3} > 2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{\pi}{3} = -\pi + \frac{\pi}{3} = -\frac{2\pi}{3} \tag{1}$$
and that
$$\theta = 2x + \frac{\pi}{3} < 2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{\pi}{3} = \pi + \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{4\pi}{3} \tag{2}$$
Combining inequalities 1 and 2 yields 
$$-\frac{2\pi}{3} < \theta < \frac{4\pi}{3}$$
Hence, the inequality 
$$\cos\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) \geq -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \iff \cos\theta \geq -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{2\pi}{3} < \theta < \frac{4\pi}{3}$$
In the interval $(-2\pi/3, 4\pi/3)$, 
$$\cos\theta \geq -\frac{1}{2} \implies -\frac{2\pi}{3} < \theta \leq \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
Substituting $2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}$ for $\theta$ yields
\begin{align*}
-\frac{2\pi}{3} & < 2x + \frac{\pi}{3} \leq \frac{2\pi}{3}\\
-\pi & < 2x \leq \frac{\pi}{3}\\
-\frac{\pi}{2} & < x \leq \frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align*}